# Actionscript 3 drawing large rect causes huge FPS drop

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, optimization

I'll get straight to the point

I need to draw a large sized rectangle (about 5k pixels width & height, might be even more)

```
this.graphics.beginFill(0x555555,1);
this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5000, 5000);
```

Now I knew that at first, it'll take time for it to generate that big of a rectangle,
But even after, the fps is really low, especially if other things are moving on the stage,

I needed this for a game (it's the ground), is there any better simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to draw a 5000x5000 image if your application's window is just 800x600. What you can do is have the 5000x5000 bitmapdata and just copy a sub rectangle of it on to the window. `bitmapData.copyPixels` should let you do that and it is pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace one large background with multiple small backgrounds and change its position according the current view position. For example rectangle with dims of 5000 can be split into 25 "tiles" with 1000 px for width and height. You can have two MovieClips that will hold the current tile. You need 2 holders - one that holds current view and second holds the tile that will become visible when current tile left the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the game area is not scaled and you will scroll the game,  you won´t display the whole 5000 px rectangle, so you can create a ground with the same size of the stage area and place it in a layer that moves along the visible area.
Just a simple parallax.

One layer with the one color ground.
Other layer with things moving over it.

Anyway you should give more information about the game.
Vector graphics?
Bitmaps?
game area scalable?